Azure Function Migration from in-process to isolated issue while reading host json in Queue Trigger
I am migrating my Azure Function from in-process to isolated process, earlier(in-process) I was reading Host file property "maxDequeueCount" through IOptions<QueuesOptions> in Azure function constructor as QueueOptions is part of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage package and isolated model does not support this package I am not able to read maxDequeueCount value in QueueTrigger Azure Function.
"extensions": {
   "queues": {
     "maxDequeueCount": 5
   }

In-Process Modal I was using below code to read:
 public class Function
 {
     private readonly QueuesOptions queuesOptions;
     public Function(IOptions<QueuesOptions> queuesOptions)
     {
         var MaxDequeueCount = queuesOptions.Value.MaxDequeueCount;
     }

     [FunctionName("Function")]
     public void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
     {
         log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
     }
 }

Can someone help me read host json property "maxDequeueCount" within QueueTrigger Azure Function in isolated model as do not have QueueOptions ?

Please share your function code.

@VivekVaibhavShandilya added code I am upgrading app to isolated model and want to read property from host which is MaxDequeueCount

I've actually noticed that not only QueuesOptions are not available, but the values under extensions / queues are ignored by isolated process worker under .NET 8 :( Tried to configure batchSize and newBatchThreshold with no effect. Would be great to find out if there is a programatic way to configure those params like it was previously possible with QueuesOptions.
